# Do I still need to learn about managing memory now that Objective-C/Cocoa has Garbage collection?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, garbage-collection

So I finally dusted off my Objective-C/Cocoa books.. turns out they are nearly 7 years old! With Objective-C 2.0 now having garbage collection, how important are the chapters on Memory Management?

How much of a difference has Garbage Collection made?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Memory management is still really important to understand. If you're targeting an older OS, you need to do memory management. If you're using an older library, you need to do memory management. If you drop down to the Core Foundation level, you (may or may not) need to do memory management.

If you're programming for iPhone, you need to do memory management.

The garbage collector in Objective-C is outstanding - and if you can be using it, you most definitely should be - but it just doesn't cover every programming situation yet.

Answer (score 3):

Some Cocoa technologies, such as Distributed Objects, PyObjC (the Python-Objective-C bridge) plugins and CoreImage (at least last I heard; this may have been fixed) don't play well with Garbage Collection. If you're using these technologies, you will still have to use traditional memory management. Of course, as others have said, you still need to use traditional Cocoa memory management (reference counting) if you're supporting OS X 10.4, or the iPhone in your code.

On the other hand, the new GC can be very nice. It's not a free lunch however; you still need to understand the semantics of the GC system, its patterns and its limitations...just as you do with any technology.

Since many thrid-party frameworks may not yet support GC, it's probably best to still understand the reference counting system. If you follow the simple rules for object ownership given in Apple's [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011), you should always be OK.

Answer (score 3):

If you're programming the iPhone platform, you need to know retain/release, because Cocoa Touch does not have GC.

If you're going to use Core Foundation, Core Graphics, most of Core Services, or any other CF-based API, you need to know retain/release, because CF-derived objects are not GC'd by default (and you must explicitly put them out for pick-up, anyway).

If you're going to use any of the POSIX APIs or any of the rest of Core Services, you need to know alloc/free memory management. You don't even get reference-counting. (Exception: Icon Services, which also has reference-counting. APIs born from Carbon are a mess.)

So, in a word: Yes.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If you're planning on ignoring 10.4 users, then you *might* not have to worry about it; but Objective-C 2.0 isn't available on 10.4 and below, so you still have to worry about memory management on those platforms.

That said, memory management is always a useful skill, and it's not *that* hard in Cocoa anyway, so it's not a bad skill to pick up.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably worth learning about the concepts that underpin Cocoa memory management, as it's still useful in certain situations. The iPhone OS, for example does not support garbage collection. There may be other situations where it is advantageous to use manual memory management, and it's useful to have the ability to make that choice

Answer (score 1):

Understanding Cocoa's excellent memory management concepts will help you with the concept of memory management in general. I've copied the autorelease concept into a few C++ projects and it worked great. Apache and Subversion are examples of other software that also uses autorelease.

Personally I find retain/release/autorelease to be just the right level of abstraction for me. It's not magic, so if I really need to do something weird, it's easy to do so. On the other hand, the rules are so simple that it becomes second nature, to the point where you eventually just don't think about memory management anymore, it just works.

Add to this the fact that, as mentioned above, only most of Cocoa supports garbage collection, while what you are writing is C, so any code you write and/or use that isn't Cocoa will need to be manually managed. This includes CoreAudio, CoreGraphics, and so on.

(Yes, CF objects work with GC, but only if you explicitly enable it for each object, and I found it hard to learn the GC-CF rules)

In summary: I never use the garbage collector myself (and the only time I did so it was very painful, as I had some C++ and CG in the mix), and as far as I know, most Cocoa coders are very used to retain/release/autorelease and use that.